# Git push & pull file permission changes

Tags: linux, windows, git, file-permissions

I have a project on my production server `linux1`.

1. I copied the project from `linux1` to my Windows PC with Windows FileZilla.
2. Then I copied it to my test server `linux2` from my Windows PC with Windows Filezilla.
3. On the `linux2` test server I made some file permission changes on the files and also changed some of the code.
4. Then I copied the project from `linux2` test server back to my Windows PC with Windows FileZilla.

If I now push the project from my Windows PC to my Git repository, and if I then pull the project on my production `linux1` server, will the file permissions on `linux1` change? Or will this just update the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git only tracks one permission: the executable bit. All files are stored as 644 (owner `rw-`, group and other `r--`) or 755 (owner `rwx`, group and other `r-x`).

When you `pull` on your production server files' executable bits will be updated according to how they were committed. Other permissions and file ownership are not tracked. The user doing the `pull`ing needs permission to modify the files on the local filesystem and will probably become the owner of any modified files.

If you need further control over permissions you can run a script. Alternatively, use a deployment tool that has more robust control over file permissions (that's not what Git was designed to do).

As a side note, it would probably be simpler to just use `git clone` / `fetch` / `pull` on your staging server instead of going through your Windows PC.